# Scheduling tasks a certain amount of time after login

Tags: bash, login, schedule

I have written a python program that reads from email. If a certain string is received from email then it does nothing. But if the python program does not receive that string, it runs a bash script, the bash scripts shuts the computer down.

I want to run this python program 2 minutes after user is logged in.

What I tried:
I added a sleep timer in the python program, and added the program in '.profile' file in my home folder. But it is not very smooth to wait for 2 minutes after login for the computer to start.

So is there any way to run the python program 2 minutes after login without disrupting startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome Shell and desktops derived from Gnome support `X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay` in the `.desktop` launcher of the program that is to be autostarted. These launchers are located under `~/.config/autostart` (for the current user only) or `/etc/xdg/autostart` (for all users). Edit the launcher and add a line in the sense

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=120
```

A method working on any desktop involves the use of the `sleep` command, which is incorporated in the `Exec=`  line like

```
Exec=sh -c "sleep 120 && myapp"
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I created a new .desktop file in /etc/xdg/autostart/. Added X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=120 at the end.

Comment: Can I ask you how you became such an expert. What do I have to learn to know such intricacies? (You don't have to answer sir.)